# NGINX conf file not loading static files

Tags: nginx

With the following .conf file, nginx is unable to load static files:

my static files and my index.php are located both in /public.
Also i'm using symfony 5 and ansible/ansistrano to provision and deploy.

Do you know where can be the error in the file?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/current/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
    # nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
    # request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
    # location /bundles {
    #     try_files $uri =404;
    # }

   location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
       include fastcgi_params;

       # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
       # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
       # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
       # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

       # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
       # current version of your application, you should pass the real
       # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
       # FPM.
       # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
       # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
       # for more information).
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
       # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
       # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
       # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
       internal;
   }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
}
```

When I change root from `root /var/www/example.com/current/public;` to `root /var/www/example.com/current;` it's able to load the home page and it's static files, but you're not able to navigate to other urls.

If you need more information please tell me.

Comment: Where in your filesystem are the static files?

Comment: in ```/var/www/example.com/current/public```

Comment: Your files have a path, e.g. `/public/css/mainstyles.css`, so this should correspond to a file located at `/var/www/example.com/current/public/css/mainstyles.css` and nginx should be configured with `root /var/www/example.com/current;`.

Comment: I've done what you told and i'm getting the following error ```FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 188.114.110.179, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"```

Comment: Your `index.php` is in the wrong directory. It must be in `/var/www/example.com/current`.

Comment: Or, you can have everything in the `public` directory, but then you must not use `/public` in your URLs in your code and HTML.

Comment: Don't know why, but adding these 2 lines seems that it solved the problem ```fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/current/public$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;```

Comment: Have you found solution? Why $realpath_root doesn't work?